# ubuntu releases via http instead of https?

Tags: iso

I'm a bit paranoid and often want to download from https. Here's via http http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.10.1/SHA256SUMS
I could not find it via https. Actually I just need sha256sums via https, download itself don't care.
My question is different to another question as I'm interested about ISO sha256sums and ISO itself.

I also found that https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website-content/+bug/1534967

Comment: Https does NOT add extra security. The only thing that needs fixing is your level of paranoia ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind really? for me to modify 2 files and serve them modified would not be an issue if this is not via https. BTW I'm not along who cares. See above I provided a link to a bug raised 2 years ago. With https it is another story

Comment: @Rinzwind for initial download, TLS or at least hashes via a TLS connection *would* improve security.

Comment: Not in the very least @vidarlo  And user1325696 a bug 2 years old about https. What that says ME is that the person filing the bug does not understand what https does and what needs to be done to validate the download.

Comment: I overlooked signed isos. My mistake :)

Comment: @Rinzwind if I'm windows user who wants to install Ubuntu what do I do to validate download?